# How to run Unit test in yeoman

Tags: html, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I have this link to a project that is using `grunt`: https://github.com/brunoscopelliti/ng-unique/.

How do I run the unit tests in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/brunoscopelliti/ng-unique/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L128) you can see the tasks registered.

There is currently three registered tasks;

```
grunt.registerTask('build-js', ['jshint', 'karma:unit', 'uglify:ngUnique']);
grunt.registerTask('build-css', ['sass:prod']);
grunt.registerTask('build-all', ['build-css', 'build-js']);
```

As you can see from the source, the `build-js` task includes running the `karma:unit` configuration.

To trigger this registered task, you have to run `grunt build-js`, or if you just want to run the Karma configuration you have to run `grunt karma:unit`.

Answer (score 2):

> grunt test

should work

you should configure your grunfile with test env as well like you have for build , debug or run, in case it's not configured i.e :

> grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'mochaTest', 'karma:unit']);